# How do I create a directory at /0 on Android?

Tags: java, android, path, permissions

I'm having a problem with my users (Android).  They delete the app, and their data is gone.  They expect it not to be.

Browsing my phone, I see a lot of apps put a folder right off of /internal shared storage.  I.E. I click on internal shared storage and there's a bunch of folders for various apps with data in them that doesn't go away if I uninstall the app.

This is what my customers want.  This is what will stop them from writing me and accusing me of destroying their data.

How do I get a path to that folder, and what permission do I need to write there?

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() will give you a path to the root of external storage. This path is mostly /storage/emulated/0. You can create folders there in the normal way. And hee use a file manager that shows you /storage/emulated/0 instead of internal /0 or other confusing stuff. And you need... WRITE permission.

Answer (score 0):

First off, deleting when the app is gone is how Android works.  Anything else is a bug that you should expect to see fixed.

Secondly, you can't put anything right in / anymore.  There was a time you could, but that's long since gone.

Third, have you looked into Android Data Backup?  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup   This will work even on a new device, so its a better path forward anyway